# Skipping if condition in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using following code snippter on button click event. Issue is if I don't select radio button than it gives me alert undefined but if I use same condition that is if I equate value of same in if condition than it escape condition.
From below code I am not getting `alert("Select action to perform.");` as this if condition is skipped.

```
 $('#actionbutton').click(function(){ 

        alert('HI SANKALP');
        var manageradiorel = $('input[name="managerelradio"]:checked').val();
        var parentid = <?php echo $parentid; ?>;
        var childid = $('#managechild').val();
        var sgid = <? echo $_GET["s"]; ?>;
        var relationship = $('#childsgrel').val();
        alert(manageradiorel);
        if(manageradiorel == "undefined"){
            alert("Select action to perform.");
            return false;
            }
        alert("Next time");

     });
```

Comment: undefined is a type, not a string. Have you tried if(manageradiorel == undefined)?

Comment: a proper way to check for undefined variables is `if(typeof variable === 'undefined') ...`

Comment: veritas speaks the truth

Answer (score 2):

in Javascript there are two optimal ways to determine if a variable exists.  One is more descriptive than the other.

1. `if (manageradiorel)`
2. `if (typeof manageradiorial == "undefined")`

Update:

If you have access to Jquery 1.6 or higher, I highly recommend using the [jQuery prop() method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of val();

Comment: Be careful with the first form.  `if (manageradiorel)` does not only determine if the variable exists.  It will also evaluate to false if the variable exists, but it has a falsey value such as `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `if(manageradiorel == "undefined")` to `if(manageradiorel === undefined)`

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
if(manageradiorel){...}
```

Comment: Be careful with this. `if (manageradiorel)` does not only determine if the variable exists. It will also evaluate to false if the variable exists, but it has a falsey value such as `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, etc...